# Problem with fluid

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

[image]
[image]

I am have a problem with my fluid simulation. When I try to simulate, the fluid distorts itself and clips through the wineglass. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The normals of the fluid object are wrong. Switch to edit mode and select everything, then recalculate the normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.